# SQL Server OpenQuery - ORA-01841 - (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to pass a date parameter in an OPENQUERY below. I have attempted formating the MOD_DT variable but I am running into ORA-01841 - (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0" error. What am i missing? Appreciate the assistance.

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000),@MOD_DT varchar(12)
SELECT @MOD_DT = '20220704'
SELECT @TSQL = 'select * from OPENQUERY([MyLinkedServer], ''select * from pubs.dbo.authors 
where trunc(mod_dt) >= ''''@MOD_DT'''' '')'
--print @TSQL
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

UPDATED Query in order to pass a date parameter to openquery script. I tested this and I am able to pull back the records. I basically converted the date column to a varchar and wrapped the parameter with + symbol

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000),@MOD_DT varchar(12)
SELECT @MOD_DT = '20220704'
SELECT @TSQL = 'select * from OPENQUERY([MyLinkedServer], ''select * from pubs.dbo.authors 
where to_char(mod_dt, ''''YYYYMMDD'''') ) >= '''' + @MOD_DT + '''' '')'
--print @TSQL
EXECUTE (@TSQL)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just do a normal select like this `select * from [MyLinkedServer].pubs.dbo.authors 
where mod_dt >= @MOD_DT` and declare the variable `@MOD_DT date`?

Comment: @Charlieface, don't think that is possible with `OPENQUERY`. It expects a constant string in the `query` string.

Comment: As I said, just do a bare linked server query, don't bother with `OPENQUERY`

Comment: I guess OP needs the date to be as a parameter

Comment: Seems like you're trying to pass in a string literal and compare it against a date column in Oracle. If you're married to `OPENQUERY` instead of using the linked server connection directly then you'll probably want to convert the passed-in string literal to an Oracle date with something like `TO_DATE('20220704', 'YYYYMMDD')`.

Comment: Basically looking to pass the @mod_dt as a variable - not a constant string. I think the TO_DATE function is the closest but I can't seem to get it to work in this case

Comment: So what is wrong with a bare linked server query, you should be able to use variables on that like I showed?